# Bootstrap carousel conflict flexslider

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexslider

I used Bootstrap carousel. If I include flex-slider in the item, the flex slider is not working. If I remove bootstrap.js, the flex slider is working. But the carousel is not working.

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">img here</div>
<div class="item">img here</div>
<div>
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li> img here</li>
    <li>img here</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>



Script:
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
```

Or Please suggest other slider. I want to display nested slider. Anyone help should be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21793695/edit) to include the minimal complete code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Flexslider 2.2 works with jQuery 1.7 You need to download and include jquery.flexslider-min.js and flexslider.css from http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html. Then include the following javascript on your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
// The slider being synced must be initialized first
$('#carousel').flexslider({
animation: "slide",
controlNav: false,
animationLoop: false,
slideshow: false,
itemWidth: 210,
itemMargin: 5,
asNavFor: '#slider'
});

$('#slider').flexslider({
animation: "slide",
controlNav: false,
animationLoop: false,
slideshow: false,
sync: "#carousel"
});
});
</script>
```

then your HTML should be in this structure:

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li>
  <img src="slide1.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide2.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide3.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide4.jpg" />
</li>

</ul>
</div>

<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li>
  <img src="slide1.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide2.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide3.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide4.jpg" />
</li>  
</ul>
</div>
```